# Is it possible to store keys securely but still use them?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, private-key

I’ve created a cryptocurrency trading bot that I want to have other people be able to use.

For regular uses having it run on their pc 27/7 is not ideal and setting up their own cloud server is too complicated/hassle.

I wanted to create my own application where they just set all the parameters on their end and send them to the server and then they don’t have to deal with any of the rest.

The issue is that for this bot to work I need their wallets private key to be able to make trades. I obviously want to store this securely (hash & salt & bcrypt) but doing so means I don’t have the key to be able to make the trades. I feel like there is no possible way to be able to ensure both the security of these keys and be able to use them.

Comment: `I need their wallets private key` this is a problem. The private key should never leave the user's device. Why should I trust you with my private key? This is a good way to get shoot at by angry mob `hash & salt & bcrypt` this is how password hashes are compared, not how data are encrypted. `both security.. able to use them` This is always a tradeoff.  And at the end,  what is the question here?

Comment: @gusto2 the question is how can i possible have a bot that trades for them without exposing their private key. To make a trade on the blockchain you need to have the private key.